# What is the best practice for using private Maps, Slices in golang?

Tags: dictionary, go, slice

I would like to be notified when a map is updated so that I can recalculate the Total. My first thought was to keep the map private, and expose an add method. This works, but then I needed to be able to allow the map to be read and iterated over (Basically, read only or a copy of the map). What I found was that a copy of the map is sent, but the underlying array, or data is the same and actually gets updated by anyone who uses the "getter".

```
type Account struct{
        Name string
        total Money
        mailbox map[string]Money // I want to make this private but it seems impossible to give read only access - and a public Add method
}
func (a *Account) GetMailbox() map[string]Money{ //people should be able to view this map, but I need to be notified when they edit it.
        return a.mailbox
}
func (a *Account) UpdateEnvelope(s string, m Money){
        a.mailbox[s] = m
        a.updateTotal()
}...
```

Is there a recommended way of doing this in Go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you could have private data and a public iterator that returns a copy of the next key/value pair upon each call, no ?

Iterators are less present in Go than in languages that don't have built-in constructs married to particular data-structures. Nevertheless they're as easy to make as anywhere else, and pretty much as easy to use, save for the fact that there's no language syntax to range an iterator. For example, `bufio.Scanner` is just an iterator with a bit of convenience cruft grafted on...

Comment: This sounds like the right approach to me. I'll look into creating an iterator, then mark this right if I can get the functionality that I want.

Comment: You may be interested in that blog post, that shows a nice exploration of various approaches to implement iterators in Go : http://ewencp.org/blog/golang-iterators/

Comment: (given that you're working on a map, and keeping performance considerations in mind, you may want to stick to "pattern 1" with callbacks)

Comment: Thanks, great article. Exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 3):

It may just be better to return a clone of the map (not the map value but everything). Same goes for slices.

Note that maps and slices are descriptors. If you return a map value, it will refer to the same underlying data structures. See blog post [Go maps in action](http://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action) for details.

Create a new map, copy the elements and return the new map. Then you don't have to worry about who modifies it.

For making a clone of the map:

```
func Clone(m map[string]Money) map[string]Money {
    m2 := make(map[string]Money, len(m))

    for k, v := range m {
        m2[k] = v
    }
    return m2
}
```

Testing the `Clone()` function (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/a05sApe9sS)):

```
m := map[string]Money{"one": 1, "two": 2}
m2 := Clone(m)
m2["one"] = 11
m2["three"] = 3
fmt.Println(m) // Prints "map[one:1 two:2]", not effected by changes to m2
```

And so your `GetMailbox()` method:

```
func (a Account) GetMailbox() map[string]Money{
    return Clone(a.mailbox)
}
```

Comment: Supposing the map is small enough, and the function does not get called often... The advantage of your approach though is atomicity. The caller does not need to worry about the map changing while he's iterating it indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily expose iteration over private data with closures.
If you want to disable modification, just don't pass the map parameter, but only keys and values, or only keys or only values, whatever are your needs.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type M map[string]int

type S struct {
    m M
}

func (s *S) Foreach(fn func(M, string, int)) {
    for k, v := range s.m {
        fn(s.m, k, v)
    }
}

func main() {
    s := S{m: make(M)}
    s.m["xxx"] = 12
    s.m["yyy"] = 254
    s.m["zzz"] = 138

    s.Foreach(func(m M, k string, v int) {
        fmt.Println(k, v)
        m[k] = v + 1
    })

    s.Foreach(func(m M, k string, v int) {
        fmt.Println(k, v)
        m[k] = v + 1
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the "recommended" ways would be to *document* that users of Mailbox must not modify the map (possibly even exporting it).

Other languages promote coding like "If I just make most things private and const than users of my code won't be able to miss-use my code and all is fine". I always understood the Go philosophy to be more like "If a user of my code doesn't read my documentation or is willingly not sticking to it his code will break anyway, even if I encapsulate everything."

E.g. in Go (as in C, Java, etc.) there is no way to indicate that some code is (or is not) safe for concurrent use: Such stuff is documentation only. There is nothing which technically prevents a user from concurrently calling unsafe-for-concurrent-use methods or functions *except* the documentation.

You will find several instances of this type of "Users must not copy/modify/whatever this field at all/after x/etc." ind the std library.